# Discerning between "a public servant" and "diplomat"

Tags: vocabulary

Machiavelli was a product of Renaissance Florence, a city-state that was struggling for expansion and survival among a competing group of similar states. As **a public servant and diplomat**, Machiavelli came to understand power politics by observing the spectacle around him without any illusions.

I am wondering what is difference between these:

a public servant

diplomat

[enter link description here](http://smartsheep.org/f-a-t-i-h-u-n-i-v-e-r-s-i-t-y-p-r-e-p-a-r-a-t-o-r-y-s-c-h-o-o-index-5)

Comment: The sentence is saying he was both. I don't understand what is confusing you. Would you explain a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a *public servant* is an official concerned with domestic affairs in his or her own jurisdiction, whereas a *diplomat* is sent on missions to places outside that jurisdiction, representing it.

Comment: Another way you could describe how they differ is that a diplomat is one type of public servant – so is a mayor; so is a congressman. In other words, "All diplomats are public servants, but not all public servants are diplomats."